# If $V$ is a normed space then $g\in V'\iff g_R\in V_{R}'.$

Tags: functional-analysis

I am reading a book on Functional Analysis which presents the following lemma:
[image]

I am reading the proof of the last claim starting with "If, in addition, V is a normed space..."

By $(5.6)$ we have 
$$|g(v)|^2 = |g_{R}(v)|^2 + |g_{R}(iv)|^2.$$
Hence if $g\in V'$ then for any $v\in V$ 
$$|g_{R}(v)|\leq |g(v)|\leq ||g|| \cdot ||v||.$$
Then the author says that this implies that $g_{R}\in V_{R}'.$ I don't understand how one can deduce this? Perhaps someone can explain?

**Note**: $V$ is assumed to be an arbitrary complex vector space. However, it can be regarded as a real vector space simply by restricting scalar multiplication to real numbers; this vector space is called $V_{R}.$

Comment: Note that your gᵣ is nothing but the real part of g and from the endmost inequalities you deduced that gᵣ is bounded on closed unit ball of Vᵣ whenever g is bounded linear functional. Hence gᵣ is a continuous real linear functional.

Comment: I thought that the dual consisted of only linear functionals. I did not know that they had to also be continuous. Is that what you are claiming?

Comment: Yes , you are right ; here dual has been trated as topological dual. In case when your normed space is finite dimensional all linear functionals are continuous i.e. then topological dual is same as algebraic dual ; otherwise not.